# Finding expensive styles without continuous paint mode

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome's continuous painting mode is very useful for [determining what elements/styles on a page are slow to paint](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/02/Profiling-Long-Paint-Times-with-DevTools-Continuous-Painting-Mode). This feature was [quietly removed in chrome 46](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=515763).

What is the best technique for finding expensive styles/elements now? Any articles or posts about alternative approaches would be very useful!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/devtools-timeline-now-providing-the-full-story) article for a more detailed explanation.

The quick answer is that you can use the Timeline to identify long paint times, then use the Paint Profiler to see what paint commands are taking a long time. Once you have a long paint command identified, you can right-click on the command and Reveal in elements panel.

From the linked article:
[image]

This covers most of the use cases that I used Continuous paint mode for.